# How to handle flyway when the db is down

Tags: database, spring-boot, flyway

This is my first time that i use flyway and i need help.
In lifetime of the microservice the postgres DB can shut down. I want to know how can flyway can get connection to the db again when it is up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I know, you could use `connectRetries` while configuring flyway. For example:

```
flyway{
    url = <Your url>
    user = <Your user>
    password = <Your password>
    driver = <Mysql/Postgres Driver>
    schemas = <Your schema>]
    connectRetries = 3
    locations = <Migration file location>
}
```